# Is there a ready-to-run Solaris virtual machine for VMWare?

Tags: solaris, vmware

I would like to test some scripting on a Solaris machine. Is there a VMWare virtual machine with Solaris that I can download and use directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not offically but you are able to download an Oracle Virtualbox image of Solaris 11.1 (for x86) [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn/solaris/11_1/OracleSolaris11_1-VM.tgz).

You don't have to install VirtualBox, you can download the portable version [here](http://www.vbox.me/).

Inside Virtualbox you can convert the VirtualBox Image to a VMWare Image. (or run it)

Comment: I just tried it, and it works fine. If you don't want to register at Oracle, you can just download the Oracle Virtualbox image of Solaris 11.1 (for x86) at http://foss.coep.org.in/vdisks/vdi/

Comment: The download is an OVA file, which is a format *recognised* by VMWare, but unfortunately doesn't seem to be directly compatible as-is. (I was able to create a virtual machine with VMWare Player, and get to a boot menu, but after that the operating system immediately panicked).

Answer (score 0):

The official page for [Oracle Solaris 11 VM Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/virtual-machines-1355605.html) is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/virtual-machines-1355605.html). You need to accept the OTN License and can then download an "Oracle Solaris 11.1 VM for Oracle VM VirtualBox".